# Using Exp:resso RSVP on two Channels

Tags: ee2, expresso

I'm currently working on a Multi Language site with Biber's MLS.

I'm using Exp:presso's RSVP addon (it is brilliant!) to manage attendance.  The only problem is that I have 2 event channels (one per language) named events_en and events_es.  On the RSVP preferences you can only pick one channel to show the RSVP Form in.

What I want to do is have the RSVP Form show up on the default language Event page and on the tranlated Event page, but that the attendance is shared between them, since its really only one event.

I have the RSVP form and attendance code in a embed template, and tried using conditionals and custom fields to pass the entry_id of the default language event, but the form still doesn't show up.

Anyone has any idea on how to get RSVP working with two channels?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the language code? Biber's MLS prepares a global variable "language_code".

I think, you are using code for events like:

```
{exp:rsvp:member_events parse="inward"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="events" entry_id="{entry_ids}"}
        <!-- event details -->
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:rsvp:member_events}
```

For the language preference update code like:

```
{exp:rsvp:member_events parse="inward"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="events_{language_code}" entry_id="1|{entry_ids}"}
        <!-- event details -->
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:rsvp:member_events}
```

You can notice, I am using {language_code} within channel parameter.